Great Expectations expect_column_values_to_be_unique with nulls in columns
I'm developing a solution to make a data quality check in one column, and already used the rule expect_column_values_to_be_unique in many other columns like the following:
df.expect_column_values_to_be_unique(column="A", result_format="COMPLETE")

Although my column contains null values, so I was wondering if there's some sort of other parameter that'll allow is to ignore the null values of the column and then run the expect_column_values_to_be_unique check.

The default behavior in Great Expectations is to ignore nulls in expect_column_values_to_be_unique so it should work like you're describing.
